# Set a custom entry file for Metro dev server in React Native build

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, metro-bundler

I'm writing some scripts that do custom React Native builds for unit testing and such, specifying a custom entry file for the `react-native-xcode.sh` script using the `ENTRY_FILE` env variable. This is super useful and great. I'm able to do release builds no problem, and they work just fine, so basically I can build a RN app from any entry file at will. However, when I try a `Debug` variant build, metro doesn't seem to know about my special custom entry file, and gives me this error:

```js
None of these files exist:
  * index(.native|.ios.js|.native.js|.js|.ios.json|.native.json|.json|.ios.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.ios.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)
  * index/index(.native|.ios.js|.native.js|.js|.ios.json|.native.json|.json|.ios.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.ios.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)
    at ModuleResolver.resolveDependency (/Users/justin/dev/enmesh/testutilsnative/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/ModuleResolution.js:165:15)
    at ResolutionRequest.resolveDependency (/Users/justin/dev/enmesh/testutilsnative/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/ResolutionRequest.js:52:18)
    at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (/Users/justin/dev/enmesh/testutilsnative/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph.js:285:16)
    at /Users/justin/dev/enmesh/testutilsnative/node_modules/metro/src/lib/transformHelpers.js:267:42
    at Server.<anonymous> (/Users/justin/dev/enmesh/testutilsnative/node_modules/metro/src/Server.js:841:41)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (/Users/justin/dev/enmesh/testutilsnative/node_modules/metro/src/Server.js:99:24)
    at _next (/Users/justin/dev/enmesh/testutilsnative/node_modules/metro/src/Server.js:119:9)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
IN RESOLVER
Error: Unable to resolve module `./index` from ``:
```

Does anyone know how I can get the Debug build of the app to interface properly with the Metro development server, so I can debug my app builds better? Any guidance here would be greatly appreciated!

Metro is just getting launched automatically by the `xcodebuild` process, which I'm calling like this:

```
const args = {
  simulator: device,
  configuration: variant,
  scheme,
  projectPath: xcodeProjectPath,
  device: undefined,
  uuid: undefined,
  packager: true,
  verbose: true,
  port: 8081,
  terminal: undefined,
};

const xcodebuildSpawnOptionsArgs: any = {
  ...args,
  cwd: folder,
  env: {
    PLATFORM: 'ios',
    ENTRY_FILE: builtEntryFilePath,
  },
};

const buildProcess = spawn(
  'xcodebuild',
  xcodebuildArgs,
  getProcessOptions(xcodebuildSpawnOptionsArgs),
);
```